# Adding search to resolv.conf prevents FQDN searches

Tags: domain-name-system, resolv.conf

I added the following line to my resolv.conf to allow for shorthand querying servers on my local domain.

search local.

If I have a server named myserver.local I can ping the server using "ping myserver", however if I try to "ping myserver.local" it stalls and fails to return an IP address.  Pinging other hosts, such as google.com works as expected.

Is there a way that I can make both "ping myserver.local" and "ping myserver" work correctly?

Comment: Are you sure adding local into your resolv.conf is the right place?  Zeroconf != DNS.

Comment: I'm adding local as a shortcut so I don't need to type the full fqdn in each time, I can just type the first part.  The search option has documentation in the resolv.conf man page.

Comment: Yes, it is is a perfectly valid for DNS, but do you actually have a **DNS ZONE** for `.local`?  Or are you using avahi/bonjour/zeroconf.  Zeroconf is NOT DNS, so the configuration for the DNS resolver is probably not going to be very useful for you.  If you actually have a DNS zone, and you have disabled any Zeroconf facilities in your systems, then ignore my comment.

Comment: Yes, I have a bind server setup and serving out .local

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that this was not an issue with resolv.conf, but nsswitch.conf.  There seems to be some issues with DNS resolution and mdns4_minimal if the application is 64bit.  There is a few documented bugs but just to link one: [Ubuntu Launchpad Bug#140663](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/nss-mdns/+bug/140663).

Uninstalling the package libnss-mdns resolved my issue.

Answer (score 1):

You need to remove the . after local:

```
search local
```

Assuming you have a dns resolver setup for your local domain, it should work as you're describing.

Comment: The . signifies the root level and should be valid syntax.  Nevertheless I did try your suggestion and it didn't work.  Thanks for the help though